# gtm.start firing twice (or more) on the same page causing two Container Loaded events

Tags: triggers, tags, google-tag-manager

I have an issue on any page within a specific domain, where for every page load I have two Container Loaded events. Now this wouldn't bother me normally, but the DataLayer object I need only loads in the second gtm.start event, while my tag fires on the first gtm.start, so that the DLV is undefined when I need it.
Can I do anything GTM-side so that the DLV populates on the first Container Loaded event?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkJWZ.png)

The container loaded more times than needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your website has 3 GTM installed. So the sequence here is very important.

You might need to check with your engineer or you can do it yourslef.

Currently the order looks like:

```
GTM-A.js

Datalayer you need

GTM-B.js

GTM-C.js
```

So I would recommend your order should adjust to

```
Datalayer you need

GTM-A.js

GTM-B.js

GTM-C.js
```

The core idea is make your datalayer push before any gtm.js code. This would make sure the GTM containers detect the datalayer you need when loading.

Otherwise. Make the datalayer push with an event name. So you can make your page_view event with that datalayer event.

> But not very recommend this way. Only if you can not modify the order.